# How to make a banner image that scrolls but the size remains fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am not sure what the exact term is but I would like to implement a banner image that has this sort of scrolling effect as someone goes further down in the page.

An example of this effect is the banner image for [this site](http://www.mentorship.io/).

Notice that when one scrolls down the rest of the image is displayed also scrolling. What is this called? And how can I implement it?

I am using Twitter Bootstrap & ruby on rails so would prefer the easiest way to implement compatible with bootstrap but any will do really, I'll figure it out from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `background-attachment:fixed;` [info here (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment)

This is also the technique used in your linked example. And here is an example :

```css
div{
    background-image: url(https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8760/17195790401_ceeeafcddb_o.jpg);
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    height:200px;
    margin:200px 0;
}

.s{
     background-image: url(https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8461/8048823381_0fbc2d8efb.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="s"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="s"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="s"></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: On the site I linked the image appears to not just remain fixed but also move up how can I add that?

Comment: @user3597950 you could ask a new question for this as it is not the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just apply position:fixed; in CSS to your element and then position it correctly with top:x; and left/right:x; for example:

```
#banner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 250px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: On the site I linked the image appears to not just remain fixed but also move up how can I add that?

Answer (score 1):

This thing is called "sticky navigation" and there is a number of jQuery plugins for that, i.e. [this one](http://stickyjs.com/)

Also, look up CSS `position: fixed;`

Comment: On the site I linked the image appears to not just remain fixed but also move up how can I add that?